# Can't select / click button using Selenium WebDriver w Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to click a button with Selenium Web Driver.

(I think it is written in Angular??)

URL is https://www.truelocal.com.au/search/accountants/canberra

It's the green button at bottom of page with "Load More Results"

Element page source is ...

```
<button class="btn btn-full btn-add js-review-open" ng-class="{true:'btn-loading', false:''}[vm.loadingMore]" ng-hide="vm.checkResultsOffset()" ng-click="vm.loadMoreResults()" aria-hidden="false" style="">

  <!-- ngIf: vm.loadingMore==true -->
  <!-- ngIf: vm.loadingMore==false -->
  <span ng-if="vm.loadingMore==false" class="ng-scope" style="">LOAD MORE RESULTS</span>
  <!-- end ngIf: vm.loadingMore==false -->
</button>
```

The only thing I can really do is

```
elm = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'LOAD MORE RESULTS')]")
```

But I can't get the button to click.

Any help please?

Comment: are you getting any relevant stack trace which shows why the test is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will keep clicking on the load more button until there is no such button is left to be clicked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.truelocal.com.au/search/accountants/canberra")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    try:
        link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[ng-click='vm.loadMoreResults()'] .ng-scope")))
        link.click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(link))
    except:
        break
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help @Shahin

Answer (score 0):

To click the button with text `LOAD MORE RESULTS` we have to wait for the button to render properly as the button is an `Angular Element`. So you can use the following code block :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-full btn-add js-review-open']/span[@class='ng-scope']"),'LOAD MORE RESULTS')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-full btn-add js-review-open']/span[@class='ng-scope']").click()
```